# MySQL returns more than one row with AND operator match

Tags: join, mysql-5.6

I have two tables 1:n relationship, customer to orders the schema is in the `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6842e/1` I have created.

The key in customer is composite `id` and `type`. I am trying to get the email address from the customer table where the `order_id is = 2`

So the query is:

`SELECT email FROM customer c, orders o WHERE o.custId = c.id AND o.id = 2`

This is returning two rows even though I specified `o.id = 2`

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6842e/1)

How to get just the email where `o.id = 2` and that rows `foreign key = primary key` of `customer table`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your schema doesn't make a whole lot of sense, unfortunately. Firstly, you have multiple customers linked to the same order. Secondly, since `custId` does not uniquely identify a customer (it's missing a `type`), you can't use it as a foreign key (which would have been obvious if you actually tried to declare it). Rethink your data model.

Comment: @mustaccio thank you for the suggestions, yes you're right about the multiple customers with same order this as a rushed fiddle I have an updated one here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5162e8/1 my question essentially is why are two rows returning when the `o.id` is specified as 1. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if we tried to simplify the query:
`SELECT email FROM customer c, orders o WHERE o.custId = c.id AND o.id = 2` we will get the following:
1- Get `o.id = 2` and that will return (2, 1) row (the command will return only two, I have pasted the whole raw to pinpoint the row). 
2- now let us search for custId from the result of point one (the result will be 1). 
3- now the command will return email address where the custId=1

```
  (1, 'G','test1@mail.com'),
  (1, 'R','test3@mail.com'),
```

after filteration it will be test1@mail.com and test3@mail.com